# ESXi root permissons restoring

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am using VMware ESXi 4.1 for running my virtual machines. Once i accidentally set "no access" permissions for user "root" over vSphere interface. AS root is my only account, i `ve lost everything, even SSH and Local Tech Support rejects root credentials. Only i have is acces to the System customization menu. If any way to restore root user permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this a [VMware KB Article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1317898) the only solution for ESXi is to reinstall. I believe that you an do a repair reinstall that leaves the VMs unaffected. [You may need to re add the VMs to the inventory and setup the virtual networking though](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=43199).

Comment: Totally agree, I wouldn't trust anything but a reinstall.

Comment: Problem resolved by reinstalling ESXi. Fortunately, all VM left on datastore, thanks for answer.